# Cannot edit a dictionary after reading it from a plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I store an NSMutableDictionary in a plist file.
and when I read it into a property of my object, I need to be able to edit it.
my properties pointer is NSMutableDictionary only,
However the object which gets generated from the plist is NSDictionary.

and Now I want to be able to add more key value pairs or delete few and save again.
Which I cant as it is an immutable object now.

the object gets created in init of my Model.

How should I go about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: <myfilename>];
NSMutableDictionary * mutableDict = [[dict mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Comment: Any of the methods of `NSDictionary` can be invoked on `NSMutableDictionary`, including convenience constructors. The convenience constructors then return an instance of `NSMutableDictionary` (or a concrete subclass within the class cluster).  So, you could just do `NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: <myfilename>];`

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to do

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a mutable copy of the dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary;

NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy];
```